# Best way to delete all variables when uninstalling module

Tags: hooks, configuration, installation

I'm writing a module that writes several variables (three, four variables for every content type, and other).

Which method should I use to delete them on hook_uninstall?

Is it safe to perform a query, searching "mymodule_*" variables?

Or should I loop for content types and search variabels, so call many times variable_del?

Comment: Instead of creating variables named per content type, you could use a structured variable(s) which has a known name and keys for each content type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Variables are cached, so deleting manually is fine so long as you invalidate that cache, e.g.

```
db_delete('variable')
  ->condition('name', 'mymodule_%', 'LIKE')
  ->execute();

cache_clear_all('variables', 'cache_bootstrap');
```

Comment: This query is OK provided that no-one has created a module which sits within your module namespace - eg if Views did this, it would vape variables belonging to modules like Views Block or Views MysiteCustom. For this example that probably wouldn't be a major issue, but you get the idea :)

Answer (score 1):

You also might look into the [Variable](https://www.drupal.org/project/variable) module which allows your module to use a registry, configure default values and so forth.