# How to delete all data when uninstalling a module without going in manually in PHPmy Admin?

Tags: database

Whenever I have a troublesome module, I have to uninstall it, then delete the folder, then go play around PhpMyAdmin to delete junk it left in my database.

This is prone to causing errors and breaking stuff...

Is there a way to uninstall modules cleanly, to delete ALL data?

I have no access to Drush on the server also...

Comment: I don't believe Drupal.org contrib modules would do such a thing. Seems to me that you're working with custom modules that the creator forgot or did not add a uninstall DB delete functionality to them.

Answer (score 1):

Modules should clean up after themselves. If they aren't, you should report it in the module's issue queue.

But, at least with D7, there isn't really much that should be left in the database. Most modules that create tables delete them when they are finished. The biggest area where things are left behind is in the variables table - many modules don't clean these out. You can safely delete them after module uninstall though.

Comment: `The biggest area where things are left behind is in the variables table - many modules don't clean these out` ugh... yeah that's easy to forget. [Best way to delete all variables when uninstalling module](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/138720/best-way-to-delete-all-variables-when-uninstalling-module)

Comment: Well, I just uninstalled Boostrap Gallery, and had a lot of cleaning up to do,  couldn't delete views from GUI, had to go in PHpMyadmin, some fields also had to be deleted from there. I guess that is just "normal" procedure? The modules installed new data I guess?

Comment: @BrunoVincent where did you get that module from?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_gallery  I always get modules from there, didnt' know there was any other place to get some?